# Удаление папки, содержащей исполняемый bat-файл из этого же файла

Tags: bat

Написал вот такой код:

```
timeout 2

RMDIR /s /q %~dp0
```

Он удаляет все содержимое папки, в которой исполняется, но не саму папку. Вываливается ошибка, что файл занят (что логично, потому что там исполняется мой файл). Как удалить саму папку, содержащую исполняемый файл?

Comment: а у меня работает Ваш пример без проблем. Видимо, Вы вызываете батник, находясь в каталоге, где он расположен. Попробуйте вызывать его из другого рабочего каталога, указав полный путь, типа: **C:\>c:\directory\delete.bat**